# How to compare json object in a json array by ignoring few attributes in java

Tags: java, json

I have sample transaction json like below

```
{
    "payload": {
        "header": [
            {
                "messageId": "10a0df00-c55c-4147-a3bf-e10dc9882768",
                "transactionId": "10000001",
                "customerId": "customer4148",
                "customerGroupId": "USA",
                "transactionStatus": "completed",
                "creationTimestamp": "2022-06-15 06:36:23.798",
                "currency": "USD",
                "offset": 30
            },
            {
                "messageId": "9cg8f839-ab1e-467f-b679-a3aa4f390f2a",
                "transactionId": "10000001",
                "customerId": "customer4148",
                "customerGroupId": "USA",
                "transactionStatus": "completed",
                "creationTimestamp": "2022-06-15 06:36:23.798",
                "currency": "USD",
                "offset": 30
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried using JsonAssert like below but due to vulnerabilities in the jar my CI pipeline is not allowing to use the jar

```
JSONAssert.assertEquals(expectedResponseBody, responseBody,
            new CustomComparator(JSONCompareMode.LENIENT,
                new Customization("messageId", (o1, o2) -> true)));
```

Please help me how can i compare multiple jsonobject under a json array ignoring the messagrId field efficiently

Comment: compare hash...

Comment: You can use gson/jackson library. [This](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-compare-two-json-objects) article might help you